# Trouble displaying specific item from database in MERN stack using useEffect and params.id

Tags: reactjs, redux, use-effect, mern

I am attempting to display a specific item from my mongoDB database by using the params.id in conjunction with the useEffect hook. My program compiles correctly but when I reach the page on my website nothing is displayed, not even unrelated headers and footers.

```
const ProductPage = (match) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.getProductDetails);
  const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (product && match.params.id !== product._id) {
      dispatch(getProductDetails(match.params.id));
    }
  }, [dispatch, product, match]);

  return (
//Irrelevant react styling here
  );
};
```

Above is the method I am using to try to find the specific product details which I have defined elsewhere and imported correctly

```
export const getProductDetails = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST });

    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`);

    dispatch({
      type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

I am using redux to analyse the state and the productdetails are not displaying [image: Redux State]

The products list I was able to get working properly on the previous page where all products are displayed so my error occurs only when trying to get a specific item. When I remove my useEffect() hook the code runs fine but without displaying anything (obviously). I am new to MERN stack applications and have been looking all over for help so I would really appreciate any advice.

Comment: Try to log `product` inside useEffect. By best guess is that your product is probabily not  defined, therefore your dispatch is never called. I think you want something like `if(!product || match.params.id !== product._id)` ?

Comment: Even with the if statement removed, meaning that it should run under any condition, it still has the same problem

Comment: Try to log `match.params.id` and see if the `id` is correctly received by the component

Comment: I have gotten the same problem when i attempt to log it 

`console.log(match.params.id);
`

I.E , nothing displays to my website, so i guess the problem is coming from the match.params.id

Answer (score 0):

To anyone having the same issue.

I ended up solving the problem by importing useParams from react-router-dom.

`import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";`

And using it as such:

```
const ProductPage = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.getProductDetails);
  const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;
  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (product && id !== product._id) {
      dispatch(getProductDetails(id));
    }
  }, [dispatch, product]);
```

Thanks to the answers which suggested logging the match.params.id which helped me locate the specific problem